# My animation properties are not working simultaneously

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying a simple animation of div which animates when page loads. Below you can see the GIF of the animation.

[image]

Here is the code

```css
@keyframes newActivity{      
    to{        
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 100;        
        top: 18%;
        left: 10%;        
        width:70%;
        height:80%;    
   }

}
.div:first-child {    
    animation-name:newActivity;
    animation-duration:5s;
}

div {      
    width: 290px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    background-color:red;
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:-10;  
}
```

```html
<div class='div'></div>
```

You can see that first it increases the width and adjust position and increase the height(Without animating it). Why is this happening? I want to animate all of these properties simultaneously.

Comment: I managed to improve it by removing the `position` rule from the animation (as it would be applied *after* the animation is over, not before/during) and setting default `top` and `left` values *before* the animation. However it was still messed up kind of.

Comment: Yeap still messed up. I need to change the position of the animation. Thanx i think i have figured out a way.

Comment: `position` is not a valid animation property, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have set the `to` height as a percentage, but height percentages are inherited; they only work when the parent element has a declared height.

Only the viewport has an inherent height set, so if you want to use `height: 80%` on your div, then you need to also set `html, body { height: 100%; }` in your CSS. The `html` element is the child of the viewport, and `body` is the child of `html`. This way, your div's `height: 80%;` can inherit all the way up through `body` and `html` to the viewport. See this example:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

@keyframes newActivity {
    to {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 18%;
        left: 10%;
        width: 70%;
        height: 80%;
    }
}

.div:first-child {
    animation-name: newActivity;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

div {
    width: 290px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

P.S. `position` is not a valid animation property. See a list of valid properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) on the Mozilla Developer Network.

P.P.S. if you want the animation to retain its state at the end, you can use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.